# blank screen in meteor with nitrous.io

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I've been working on an app in meteor and it's just giving me blank screen however the page title still works.

I had to double check whether it was my app or the box so I backed up my stuff, started a brand new node box and installed meteor by itself and it's giving me the same problem, has anyone else encountered this?

also, i got these errors chrome's console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.js:5903
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined domutils.js:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DomUtils' of undefined universal-events.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DomUtils' of undefined spark.js:24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Spark' of undefined preserve-inputs.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Spark' of undefined handlebars.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Spark' of undefined templating.js:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Template' of undefined global-imports.js:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.xy.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined xy.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Spark is not defined
```

Comment: try redownloading jquery? It looks like the problem is with that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, tried that but its still not working, just tried getting meteor running on cloud9 but the meteor version is outdated and it's not updating :S